# pandas conditional loc append values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have the following df

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3':["dog", "cat"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

col1    col2    col3
0   1   3   dog
1   2   4   cat
```

If I wanted to change the value in col3 in rows which col1=1 and col2=3 to fox I would do:

```
df.loc[(df.col1==1)&(df.col2==3), "col3"]="fox"

 col1   col2    col3
    0   1   3   fox
    1   2   4   cat
```

Instead of changing dog to fox I want to append it, like so:

```
col1    col2    col3
0   1   3   dog, fox
1   2   4   cat
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just join them using `+`

```
df.loc[(df.col1==1)&(df.col2==3), "col3"] = df.loc[(df.col1==1)&(df.col2==3), "col3"] + ', ' + "fox"

Out[383]:
   col1  col2      col3
0     1     3  dog, fox
1     2     4       cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `+=` operator:

```
df.loc[(df.col1==1)&(df.col2==3), 'col3'] += ', fox'

   col1  col2      col3
0     1     3  dog, fox
1     2     4       cat
```